# Receive IFileForm in Net Core Controller and forward to another (independent) API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Vue.JS application, where I upload an image to a NetCore Controller.

I'm receiving the IFileForm in the following controller:

```
[HttpPost("UpdateContactPhoto")]
public async Task<string> UpdateContactPhoto(IFormFile file){ //Forward the original IFileForm to another NetCore API.    }
```

At this point everything is working correctly. IFileForm arrives perfect.

My problem is that I need to forward this IFileForm to another API (independent of this) whose input is an IFileForm with HttpClient PutAsync, but not works.

Can someone help me?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You will need to send the underlying stream to the outgoing request body. The form file itself is just a wrapper for that when *receiving* file uploads.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this example. Note that the argument name is the same as the item added to the `form-data`:

```cs
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57985");

            byte[] data;
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                data = br.ReadBytes((int) file.OpenReadStream().Length);
            }

            ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", file.FileName);

            var result = client.PutAsync("api/v1/FileManager", multiContent).Result;

            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //do some things
            }
        }
```

You can also use this code to get the file from the `HttpContext` :

```cs
    IFormFile file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "Target url here" with your destination URL:

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var streamcontent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync("target url here", streamcontent);
```

Reference:

[HttpClient PutAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_PutAsync_System_String_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_)

[StreamContent class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.streamcontent?view=netframework-4.8)

[IFormFile interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Both `OpenReadStream` and `PutAsync` return `IDisposable`s and should therefore be wrapped with `using`.